Numerically obtain nullspace of linear PDE
I'm interested in finding all stress fields $\sigma^{\alpha \beta}(u^1,u^2)$ that solve the following linear homogenous partial differential equation:
$$ \partial_\alpha\left[\sigma^{\alpha \beta}(u^1,u^2) \partial_\beta \mathbf{r}(u^1,u^2)\right]=0$$
Here, the stress field is symmetric under index exchange, $\sigma^{\beta \alpha} = \sigma^{\alpha \beta}$ and $\mathbf{r}$ is a real, smooth three-dimensional field corresponding to a solid, curved two-dimensional surface embedded in three (Euclidean) dimensions. Both $\sigma, \mathbf{r}$ are subject to periodic boundary conditions such that increasing either argument $u^i$ by 1 does not change their value (EDIT: or rather, the stress field is strictly periodic and  $\mathbf{r}(u^1+1,u^2) = (1,0,0) + \mathbf{r}(u^1,u^2), \mathbf{r}(u^1,u^2+1) = (0,1,0) + \mathbf{r}(u^1,u^2)$)
For an arbitrary smooth surface $\mathbf{r}$ I'm interested in numerically finding all possible stress fields. I'd also be interested in analytically proving that there are at least three such stress fields, which I expect (but don't know how to prove) from the fact that the integral of the left-hand side of the equation over the surface (which corresponds to the net force induced by the stress) must vanish in each of its three components.
I've tried NDSolve and NDEigensystem but didn't make much progress. For NDSolve, it's not clear whether it's giving me correct solutions, but it's also hard to use it to figure out how many solutions there should be. For NDEigensystem (I'm pretending that the three unknown stress components are the same as the three unknown forces), it's giving me 7-10 solutions, when I expect only three. In both cases, it gives me error messages warning that the differential equation is convection dominated.
EDIT: I am interested in the general problem described above, but some entity called the community bot asked for a specific problem. A specific problem would be to numerically find and count all the solutions of the above problem for the specific surface given by
$$\mathbf{r}(u^1,u^2) = \left(u^1,u^2,\sin(2 \pi u^1) + 1.2(\sin(4 \pi u^2 + .2) + 3.4 \sin(4 \pi u^1 -.8)\sin(6\pi u^2 +.43)\right)$$

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
